# A question disappeared! Why?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, specific-question, deleted-questions

Somebody asks an SQL question, I proudly answer his question, and when I came back to see if my answer was accepted, the question had disappeared!

That [was the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568723/invalid-column-name/4568788#4568788) of the question. My question is: why? And why don't people explain why their question/answers were simply deleted!

Comment: I also voted to undelete, so now you may have a skirmish, because it has returned to life :D

Comment: Cool! It is possible to unvote the deleting? thanks anyway!

Comment: @bAN Users with 10k rep can vote to undelete. I believe it takes 5 votes to undelete a question.

Comment: Happens to me regularily as well. What worries me is that it's always the good questions that vanish. Oftentimes high-repuation users that are seemingly ashamed to have questions too.

Comment: @marcog You can read the full thresholds on [the privileges page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools), but to summarize - it's 3 votes to undelete by default, but it may take additional votes to undelete particularly popular questions (which likewise would take additional votes to delete in the first place).

Comment: @bAN it is now undeleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The poster deleted his question, about a half-hour after he asked it.

(Users with 10k rep can still see the question at the URL you noted.)

Comment: What a strange system.. So you can ask question and when you have response you delete your question.. Pfff no votes for my answer..

Comment: @bAN: I'm with you; I'd consider his actions rude.

Comment: Happened to me several times. :/

Comment: @michael Petrotta Was the deleted question voted down?

Comment: @bernd: No, 1 upvote for the Q and 2  answers w/o votes.

Comment: @bAN If the user has a habit of doing this, it will be addressed.

Answer (score 7):

May be we should prevent the user from deleting the question after someone answers the question and after some up votes. And definitely if the user marks as a right answer.

Comment: Or simply ask users who have an answer if the creator of the question can delete this one.. A kind of 'vote for delete'

Comment: Yes. `Vote for delete`.

Comment: I disagree. Each user should have a right to remove his/her question at any moment regardless of any criteria. There is no point in keeping that question alive. And as mentioned, its not that no one can see that question. Moderators can still see deleted questions.

Comment: But when somebody take time to write an answer, he is concerned by the post.. And deleting without any explaination this is rude..

Comment: If anything, I think the current rules are too strict. If a question gets a number of upvotes/answers, then the user can no longer delete it. I believe each user should have that kind of control over content they generate.

Comment: I think Moderators should be the only ones who can delete a question, if the question is a valid question and has answers it may be useful for a lot of other members / visitors, The owner of the question should be able to Request to delete his question and a moderator should act accordingly.

Comment: This facility already exists. However, the exact criteria are somewhat unknown... but certainly the relevant question here didn't meet them.

Comment: @decyclone - All content posted is ccwiki and can get reproduced straight away by other websites with attribution back. It would seem odd that they can post them but SO itself can't.

Comment: this already happens, however, it takes more than 1 answer or more than 1 vote.